# couchbase Lite and Spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, couchbase-lite

I am trying to use couch base lite (mobile) by using spring boot framework. I am not getting the perfect guide documents for reference. I have referred documents for couchbase server by using spring data couchbase. but Not having idea how to use spring data couchbase for couchbase lite.

Comment: Please suggest from where should i stat, means how should i write configurations nd all th operations by using springboot